# How to Unload mapbox before opening another mapbox instance

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

I am using Mapbox API in my android application.

I need to close the main map and start another map in another activity.

The only topic I found about this was [This Issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1638) that is talking about the web version of mapbox, not the Android, At least it gave me an idea that I need to use some kind of method to unload the first map before loading the second one.

can't find the class to call to perform this action, tried `unload()`, `finish()` and still none working.. which prevents my second map to load its own tiles.

any help with this?

Comment: You're tagging Android while linking the Web version issue. Could you clarify which platform are you targeting?

Comment: @ŁukaszPaczos I'm Using android, but the only topic I found was talking about the mapbox web version and it gave me an idea that I need to use some kind of unloading. but never found anything about the android version which I need that is why am asking here. Question updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to override and call all `MapView`'s lifecycle methods. You can follow this example - https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/first-steps-android-sdk/. There's nothing else specific to the setup that would cause two different activities from displaying the maps on their own.